# ¿Como obtener un único array?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un arreglo que lo paso por un `map`

```
  let arr = SurveySelect.map((q,i) => {
     return q.Respuestas
  });
```

`map` retorna `q.Respuestas` dentro de otro arreglo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo necesito formar un solo arreglo con sus datos

```
[
 {pregunta: 'loremimpu....', resp..},
 {pregunta: 'loremimpu....', resp..},
 {pregunta: 'loremimpu....', resp..},
 {pregunta: 'loremimpu....', resp..}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es que `arr` sea arreglo de objetos (*en lugar de un arreglo de arreglos de objetos*), entonces podrías, mapear `q.Respuestas` nuevamente y devolver el valor de la primer posición de cada elemento.

### Solución:

```
let arr = SurveySelect.map((q,i) => {
  return q.Respuestas;
});
let arr2 = arr.map(p => {
  return p[0];
});
```

### Demo:

```js
let arr = [
  [{
    pregunta: 'Pregunta 1',
    respuesta: 5,
    tipo: 'Escala'
  }],
  [{
    pregunta: 'Pregunta 2',
    respuesta: 6,
    tipo: 'Escala'
  }],
  [{
    pregunta: 'Pregunta 3',
    respuesta: 4,
    tipo: 'Escala'
  }]
];

let output = arr.map(preg => {
  return preg[0];
})
console.log(output);
```

---

### Solución 2:

Si el caso fuera que cada *arreglo interno* tuviese mas de un objeto, entonces podrías usar el método [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/apply) de [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat) el cual tomara el segundo parámetro como como la lista de arreglo a unir y así dando como resultado un arreglo de objetos.

```
let arr = SurveySelect.map((q,i) => {
  return q.Respuestas;
});
let arr2 = [].concat.apply([], arr);
```

### Demo:

```js
let arr = [
  [{
    pregunta: 'Pregunta 1',
    respuesta: 5,
    tipo: 'Escala'
  },{
    pregunta: 'Pregunta 2',
    respuesta: 3,
    tipo: 'Escala'
  }],
  [{
    pregunta: 'Pregunta 3',
    respuesta: 6,
    tipo: 'Escala'
  }],
  [{
    pregunta: 'Pregunta 4',
    respuesta: 4,
    tipo: 'Escala'
  }]
];

let output = [].concat.apply([], arr);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @HernanHumaña, he actualizado mi respuesta, dando una solución a un escenario que se me paso por alto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.